# Java substring exactly 3 letters from each word in the same string

Tags: java, substring

I've got this exercise in which I have to use the substring and from each month to only display me the first 3 letters, Jan,Feb, etc. I know I have to use months.substring(0,3) or something like that but I don't know to do a program with that, can you point me on how to do it?

```
 String months[] = {"January ", "February ", "March ", "April ", "Mai ",
 "June ", "July ", "August ", "September ", "October ", "November  ", "December "};
```

Comment: You may learn more Java before trying to apply it. You need a skill base to start doing stuffs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what you are looking for

```
for(String month : months){
   System.out.print(month.substring(0, 3) + " ");
}
```